# WITH or TO after update

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Update your profile picture with this frame.
> 2. Update your profile picture to this frame.

I asked my teacher whether the 2 is correct and she told me it is not and the correct would be the 1. I wanted convey a meaning of `Update your current profile picture and make it with this frame`(keeping the same picture but with a frame). By profile picture, I mean the social media one. I have this uncertainty because 'with' means to accompanied by, to me it means something like to do the action of updating the profile picture through(with the help of) this frame which is not the meaning I want to convey. Can I instead say

> Update your profile picture to with this frame.

If the 1 is correct, how about this if I want to say to do it with a certain app

> 4. Update your profile picture with this frame with this app.

Comment: Update your profile picture, but keep the frame. maybe?

Comment: I think "with this app" should be "in/within the app"

Comment: Both prepositions (***with*** and ***to***) are fine in the cited context. They're different ***syntactically***, but the effective meaning is the same. What you ***can't*** do is include both of them - choose one or the other.

Comment: ...I don't know (or care) exactly what "frame" means here, but if it's meaningful to to use both an "app" *and* a "frame" to perform the update, maybe you could use both. There's no problem with *Update your profile picture **to** this photo **with** this app* (where ***using*** would be an alternative to ***with***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your "profile picture" is made up of 2 things: a "frame" and a "portrait" that goes inside the frame.

> update your profile picture *with* frame B

This means you just change your frame from frame A to frame B and keep the same portrait.

> update your profile picture *to* frame B

People may understand this as the same as when using "with" but that would be because of the context. When you use "update (from) A to B", you're saying "change everything from A to B, meaning your new profile picture would be *just* the frame B, since you would change the whole "profile picture" to "frame B", which wouldn't make much sense in the context of your profile picture.

TLDR:

- "update **A** *with* **B**": **A** has **B** as a new component
- "update **A** *to* **B**": **A** is *replaced* with **B**

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnZhau