# Is "update A to B" a correct usage?

Tags: prepositions

In my writing, I use "update *old.txt* to *new.txt*" to mean that I update the file *old.txt* and get a new file *new.txt*. I wonder whether this is a correct usage, since I do not find this usage in the Oxford dictionary.

I'm aware of "change A to B". But I want to emphasize the meaning of "update".

Comment: Looks fine to me but a bit more context would be helpful to be sure.

Comment: @IMSoP I have updated the question.

Comment: @mdewey I have updated the question.

Comment: I have updated the text by removing A and putting in B.

Comment: A little more information would be nice, GenG.  Are you **updating** the file, meaning you add new text to the underlying document or are **renaming** the file, meaning only the title has changed or are you doing both?  Updating and renaming imply different things.

Comment: @EllieK Thanks. I mean only "updating". The example "update Internet Explorer to Microsoft Edge" in David Siegel's answer, where both Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge are browsers, is close to what I mean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With or Of after update.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/269480/with-or-of-after-update) The title there is misleading, since the actual example being queried asks about *Update X **with** Y* OR *Update X **to** Y*.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, this usage is not idiomatic English.

You can update an *attribute* to have a new *value*, for instance:

> Update the colour to blue

Or, in your example, update an *object* to *have* a new attribute:

> Update old.txt to the new format

But the result of that action is not a *new object*, it is *the same object, changed*.

For an update to create a new object, you need to specify how the new object relates to the process, as well as what the process is.

For instance:

> Update the format of old.txt and save as new.txt

Or if the nature of the update is obvious from context:

> Update old.txt and save as new.txt

This is a bit ambiguous though - it's not clear whether old.txt will *also* change, as well as new.txt being created. It would be clearer to specify the actions in the other order:

> Create a copy of old.txt called new.txt and update the format

The other option is that the contents are actually staying the same, but the name is changing. In that case, you should not use "update" at all, but "rename", "move", or "replace".

Answer (score 0):

I would think that  "update old.txt to new.txt"  implies discarding old.txt and replacing it with new.txt, which the user may create or may obtain from some other source, such as the publisher.

More common might be something like:

> - Update feature.dll to version 10.7
> - Update feature.dll to the version dated 6 Sept 2020.

Used in either of these ways "Update A to B" is very common in the software industry. As a professional software developer I have seen such usage thousands of times, and written it hundreds of times.

I think "update" is more often used when the name of the object stays the same, but its contents or format is changed. Butr one could also say:

> Update Internet Explorer to Microsoft Edge.

Here a thing with a different name but a similar function replaces the previous thing. The word "replace" could be used, but "update" is more specific.

Or to find a non-computer example:

> Update the fuses to circuit-breakers.

again the meaning of "update" is "replace with a newer or better version", and such a use is quite natural and would be used by fluent speakers.

Comment: I'm not convinced by "Update Internet Explorer to Microsoft Edge"; I'd probably expand it to "Update *from* Internet Explorer to Microsoft Edge", with an omitted direct subject, so in full: "Update *your browser* from Internet Explorer to Microsoft Edge". Similarly, "update [your fusebox] *from* fuses to circuit-breakers". The direct subject of "update" should be something that exists in a different form before and after, not something that ceases to exist after the update. Your "feature.dll" examples both follow that rule, but the example in the question doesn't.

Comment: @IMSoP  I can tell you that I have written "Update {app1} to {app2}" in business emails to clients at least dozens, probably hundreds of times. If usage proves correctness, this is correct. No client ever complained or indicated a failure to understand, no supervisor ever offered a correction. This is standard usage. The "from" is routinely omitted in such cases.